# Draw rectangle with aCoords tl, br corners instead of top, left in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

So I wanted to draw rectangles on canvas based on coordinates received from an external system, which uses (x1,y1) (top-left) and (x2,y2) (bottom-right) coordinates to draw rectangle whereas in Fabric.js it's a bit different such as using the **top** and **left** properties, I tried to do it using aCoords and wrote this code:

```
  addRect() {
    let square = new fabric.Rect({
      stroke: 'yellow',
      noScaleCache: false,
      strokeWidth: 10,
      strokeUniform: true,
      fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      flipX: true,
    });
    console.log(square.getCoords());

    square.set("aCoords", { tl: new fabric.Point(100, 2), br: new fabric.Point(1, 2), tr: new fabric.Point(1, 2), bl: new fabric.Point(1, 2) });

  
    this.canvas.add(square);
  }
```

This doesn't seem to work, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though from reading the API reference at [fabricjs.com](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#aCoords) it's not certain but after digging through the code a little bit I'm almost sure `aCoords` just serves as a getter. So you can't modify a shapes appearance using this property.

Instead you have update the `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` properties indivudually.

Here's an example:

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  let square = new fabric.Rect({
    stroke: 'yellow',
    noScaleCache: false,
    strokeWidth: 10,
    strokeUniform: true,
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    flipX: true,
  });

  canvas.add(square);

  let x1 = 5;
  let y1 = 25;
  let x2 = 105;
  let y2 = 55;

  square.set("top", y1);
  square.set("left", x1);
  square.set("width", (x2 - x1));
  square.set("height", (y2 - y1));

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.min.js "></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that this method would work too !

Comment: No problem Ali - glad I could help! =)